# Python 3.8: Find out the properties of detected boundaries drawn using skimage.segmentation.mark_boundaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0, scikit-image

I have an image of irregular size seeds. By using [`skimage.segmentation.mark_boundaries`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.mark_boundaries) in Python 3.8, I detected the boundaries of these seeds as shown in the figure. Now, I want to find out the all properties of these detected boundaries. How to do that? Also, I have another small doubt that how to increase the thickness of detected boundaries?

Note: I want to find out the properties of each seed (including overlapped). So, I applied the watershed algorithm and detected boundaries for each seed. Therefore, now using ***these detected boundaries*** I'm trying to find out all properties of seeds.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second input to `mark_boundaries` is `label_img`. You can use this exact input to [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) to measure region properties. The output of `mark_boundaries` is only useful for visualisation.

Comment: Sir, I used 'region = measure.regionprops(labels, intensity_image=None, cache=True, coordinates=None)' but it shows bolbs more than 300 while bolbs are only 32. Why is so?

Comment: I observed that it is repeating the values. Code I used is:
 areas = [p.area for p in region]
 print(areas)
To test I used only three blobs and the result was :
[3802, 4563, 4379]
[3802, 4563, 4379]
[3802, 4563, 4379]
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you share your full code and example image? It works perfectly fine with: `[region.area for region in measure.regionprops(np.array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]]))]`, which gives `[3, 1, 2]`. Perhaps you are doing the list comprehension *and* appending to a bigger list?